# How do determine the final URL from a link in Java

Tags: java, google-alerts

This is a link generated from Google Alerts, and I would like to get where you get redirected. So I need the URL and I would have to retrieve it with Java. I have checked for the response, but no location header redirect.

https://www.google.com/url?rct=j&sa=t&url=http://naija247news.com/2016/03/nigerian-bond-yields-rise-after-cbns-interest-rate-hike-aimed-at-luring-investors/&ct=ga&cd=CAIyGjA3ZmJiYzk0ZDM0N2U2MjU6Y29tOmVuOlVT&usg=AFQjCNGs7HsYSodEUnECfdAatG6KgY18DA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
String URL = "https://www.google.com/url?rct=j&sa=t&url=http://naija247news.com/2016/03/nigerian-bond-yields-rise-after-cbns-interest-rate-hike-aimed-at-luring-investors/&ct=ga&cd=CAIyGjA3ZmJiYzk0ZDM0N2U2MjU6Y29tOmVuOlVT&usg=AFQjCNGs7HsYSodEUnECfdAatG6KgY18DA";

String subStr = URL.substring(URL.indexOf("url=") + 1, URL.indexOf("&ct"));
```

I forgot what the starting and ending position has to be exactly, which indexes. So you would have to verify that and check it creates a substring at the right position. But the basic idea is to cut out the URL you need and nothing more. This is an example for what you forwarded. It could be that you would have to search for something else to know the end of the substring, when you have a different URL (in the provided example I look for &ct, which maybe be not be the case in another URL). You will have to look up several URLs you have to know how to cut out the URL.

Comment: please explain the what the "&ct" means. it does appear in all the urls, so this may be a solution, i just need to understand what i need to cut out. Thanks

Comment: Like I wrote, you have to know when the URL ends. In the example you posted, you can determine the end by looking for the unique substring &ct. Having the index allows you to know where to stop and cut out the substring. Same goes for the starting index in the `substring` method. Hope I made myself more clear and understandable.

Comment: thanks. though Google's feed urls vary a little and this may not work in all cases. can htmlunit be used to open the link and get the url? if so kindly direct me to an example implementation on app engine

Comment: Sorry, but I am not familiar with htmlunit, you will have to do the research yourself.